# mongodb $lookup operator based on key name

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Having two collections `tables` and `table_rows` like following:

```
tables = {
  "_id": "641ce65852a7ccd2f4a7b298",
  "name": "table name",
  "description": "table description",
  "columns": [{
    "_id": "641ce65852a7ccd2f4a7b299",
    "name": "column 1",
    "dataType": "String"
  }, {
    "_id": "641cf95543a5f258bfaf69e3",
    "name": "column 2",
    "dataType": "Number"
  }]
}

table_rows = {
  "tableId": "641ce65852a7ccd2f4a7b298",
  "641ce65852a7ccd2f4a7b299": "Example string",
  "641cf95543a5f258bfaf69e3": 101
}
```

That in a nutshell represent regular tabular data of 2 columns and 1 row like this:

| column 1 | column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Example string | 101 |

Is there any way to use `$lookup` operator to join those two collections based on `_id` from `columns` array in tables collection and based on the **key name** from `table_rows` collection? What i'm trying is to somehow join columns definitions (name, datatype, etc) along with cell values.

As you can see actual **key name** in `card_rows` collection is `_id` of column itself.

Ideally this would be single collection, but those tables can grow to hundred of columns and 10K of rows, so it is modeled as two collections to avoid unbound arrays in mongo.

Comment: How does more table rows look like. Another record with same table id and same keys?

Comment: hi @cmgchess thank you for your comment. Yes indeed, `card_rows` is keeping row data of each table. Another record (of same table) could be literally the same object like above just with different column values. Or if it is another table it would be record with different tableId and different column ids as key names.

Comment: so table_rows and card_rows is the same? also is there a way which tells which row comes first and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to start from the `table_rows`:

1. `$match` the relevant documents using the `tableId`, `$unwind` the "rows" and `$group` by columns
2. Use `$lookup` with pipeline to get the column name for each column document
3. Format

```
db.table_rows.aggregate([
  {$match: {tableId: tableId}},
  {$unset: ["tableId", "_id"]},
  {$project: {rows: {$objectToArray: "$$ROOT"}}},
  {$unwind: "$rows"},
  {$group: {_id: "$rows.k", values: {$push: "$rows.v"}}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "tables",
      let: {tableId: tableId, colId: "$_id"},
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {$expr: {$eq: ["$_id", "$$tableId"]}}},
        {$project: {
            _id: 0,
            coldata: {
              $first: {$filter: {
                  input: "$columns",
                  cond: {$eq: ["$$colId", "$$this._id"]}
              }}
            }
        }}
      ],
      as: "colName"
  }},
  {$project: {
      colName: {$first: "$colName.coldata.name"},
      values: 1,
      _id: 0
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EW3z0vH4JJR)

*If you want to avoid unbounded arrays on the query, you can drop the `$group` step...

Comment: very nice example, thank you